# How to remove a directory from URL permanently

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have my website under directory ***alpha*** in WWW.

so my url are like: www.mydomain.com/alpha/*

I want users to see just www.mydomain.com/*

```
RewriteCond $1 !^alpha/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /alpha/$1 [L]
```

Is working correctly for just www.mydomain.com. But beyond that when I click on any link ***alpha*** comes back in the URL.

I want to ***alpha*** to be completely hidden from users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the links is the best solution, but if you cannot do so then you need to add another rule to send requests with `/alpha` to the URL minus `/alpha` as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if request  starts with alpha
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /alpha/([^\ ])* [NC]
#redirect to without alpha
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^alpha/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /alpha/$1 [L]
```

Comment: its only working for domain.com...for all other links I am still getting alpha in the URL.

Comment: @AJ. can you provide the URLs that you tested with

Comment: Also now my other site on same domain is throwing 404 error.

www.mydomain.com is being redirected to www.mydomain.com/alpha

BUT www.mydomain.com/beta is throwing 404 error. What to do?